# Do bash aliases only work at beginning of line?

Tags: shell, alias

First, I ran `touch file.txt`

Next, I ran these commands:

```
alias xx="file.txt"
vim xx
```

Expected behavior: vim loads `file.txt`. Actual behavior: vim loads a new file `xx`.

Why? Is it because aliases only work if they are at the beginning of a line? For example, if I type

```
xx
```

then it does the substitution and outputs `zsh: command not found: file.txt`. So the alias works in this case.

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `zsh`? The tittle says `bash` but the error you get `command not found: file.txt.` seems to be for `zsh`. However [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452608/414186) might be useful.

Comment: I tried it in both actually, same results it seems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normal aliases whether in `bash` or `zsh` (which is the shell you seem to be using, not `bash`) are meant to alias commands and are only expanded in command position, which is at the start of the line but also after `;`, `|`, `&`, `&&`, `if`/`then`/`else`/`while`... etc, or after an alias whose value ends in a space.

The latter is so that you can do:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias ll='ls -l'
```

And then do:

```
sudo ll
```

For the shell to expand that to `sudo ls -l`.

In `zsh` though, you can also have *global* aliases with:

```
alias -g xx=file.txt
```

After which `xx` is changed to `file.txt` wherever it's found as a delimited word (before quote removal).

```
echo xx
```

Will then run `echo file.txt`, though the alias won't be expanded in `echo xxy` or `echo "xx"`, though you can also do things like:

```
alias -g '"xx"=hello; echo world'
```

after which `echo "xx"` would be changed to `echo hello; echo world` and run both `echo` commands.

Rather than an alias here, it seems you want to use a variable.

```
xx=file.txt
vim "$xx"
```

(quotes necessary in bash; in `zsh` you can shorten it to `vim $xx`).

aliases are a feature from csh, a shell from the late 70s which didn't have functions¹. In Bourne-like shells such as bash and zsh (though bash and even more so zsh are the two Bourne-like shells that borrowed most features from csh), aliases are of little use except in some specific cases where functions cannot be used such as `alias forever='while true; do'` or `alias fail='return 1'`...

---

<sup>¹ the Bourne shell also from the late 70s initially had neither functions nor aliases, though functions were added soon after circa 1983. aliases and history expansion (and the fact it was free software) contributed greatly to the popularity of csh (a shell with otherwise great flaws) and explains why those features made it to some other Bourne-like shells. Aliases (not history expansion) even went into the POSIX specification of sh (based on a subset of ksh), to the regret of its maintainers as it's almost impossible to formalise a sane language with those. There was even an attempt [at deprecating them there](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1048)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

1. You say `bash`, but your error message is from `zsh`. zsh isn't bash.  zsh and bash are both shells, with similar but not identical syntax.  They're largely compatible, but not 100%.  zsh can do some things bash can do, and bash can do some things zsh can't do.  For the most part, zsh has a lot more features and enhancements than bash.
2. From `man bash`:

> **ALIASES**
>
> Aliases allow a string to be substituted for a word when
> it is used as the **first** word of a simple command.
>
> The shell maintains a list of aliases that may be set and
> unset with the `alias` and `unalias` builtin commands (see
> SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
>
> The first word of each simple command, if unquoted, is
> checked to see if it has an alias.  If so, that word is
> replaced by the text of the alias. [...]

Run `man bash` and search for `^ALIASES` to read the full description.  For zsh-specific info on aliases, run `man zshbuiltins` and search for `alias` and `man zshmisc` and search for `^ALIASING`, which begins with:

> **ALIASING**
>
> Every eligible word in the shell input is checked to
> see if there is an alias defined for it.  If so, it is
> replaced by the text of the alias if it is in command
> position (if it could be the first word of a simple
> command), or if the alias is global.
>
> If the replacement text ends with a space, the next word
> in the shell input is always eligible for purposes of
> alias expansion. [...]

Comment: Or `info -n Aliases bash` or `info zsh Aliasing`.